# Cycling Through List of URLs Using Excel VBA

Tags: html, vba, excel

I am much more familiar with Excel now, but one thing is still baffling me - how to cycle through URLs in a loop. My current conundrum is that I have this list of URLs of packages, and need to obtain the status of each package on each page using its HTML. What I currently have to cycle through the list is:

```
Sub TrackingDeliveryStatusResults()

Dim IE As Object
Dim URL As Range
Dim wb1 As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet

Dim filterRange As Range
Dim copyRange As Range
Dim lastRow As Long

Set wb1 = Application.Workbooks.Open("\\S51\******\Folders\******\TrackingDeliveryStatus.xls")
Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("TrackingDeliveryStatusResults")

Set IE = New InternetExplorer

With IE
    .Visible = True
    For Each URL In Range("C2:C & lastRow")
        .Navigate URL.Value
        While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
        MsgBox .Document.body.innerText
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

And the list of URLs [image]

My goal here is:

- Cycle through each URL (inserts URL in IE and keeps going without opening new tabs)
- Obtain the status of the item for each URL from the HTML element
- FedEx: Delivered (td class="status")
- UPS:  Delivered (id="tt_spStatus")
- USPS: Arrived at USPS Facility (class= "info-text first)
- Finish the loop and save as a csv if at all possible (I've already done that, so I'm just posting the code portion I'm having a problem with).

My understanding is that I have to code a different if statement for each different url, since all of them have different HTML tags for their delivery status. Loops are simple, but to loop through webpages is new to me. The code has been throwing me errors no matter what changes I make.

The IE object opens up but then Excel hits an error and the code stops running.
[image]

Comment: maybe you should post your error and we could start with that

Comment: @TylerCowan I've put a pic of the error that happens.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I know how to reference HTML and do web scraping just fine - it's just the looping through the list of URLs and referencing the specific element for each that I'm not sure about.

Comment: @Tak and what gets highlighted for the object defined error

Comment: @TylerCowan For Each rngURL In Range("C2:C" & lastRow)

Comment: If I am reading this right how about `If Instr(1,URL.Value,"fedex") Then sID = "status"`. Then follow suit for UPS and USPS cases. Then search or reference the correct element using the `sID` variable. You may need to define which element you use by the type for each page as well. Also, for your error, you need to qualify the `Range ...` with a Worksheet. So `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2:C & lastRow)` ... change `Sheet1` to your sheet name. Because of your `With` block, VBA is trying to assign the `Range` property to the IE object, which is not possible.

Comment: @Tak I would start with properly referencing your range in this case it is ws1.Range("C2:C" & LastRow) also assigning the range to variant might be useful

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Thank you. I'll reconstruct the code and get back to you on it. Would there be some way of referencing the address bar in the IE object? Or would I have to open up a new page every single time it goes through in the loop? D:

Comment: @TylerCowan I haven't needed to implement the range as variant, but I'll read up on it for a refresher and definitely give it a try.

Comment: @Tak - You can just navigate to the new page in the same IE instance once you are done with the previous URL.

Comment: @TylerCowan I don't think I'm naming it right. I have this right now:  
`Set rngURL = ws1.Range("C2:C" & lastRow)`  
    `Arr = rngURL`   
And I've done this:  
`Dim rngURL As Range`  
`Dim Arr() As Variant`

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I've been having a spot of trouble with identifying the variables for sID. I've done `Dim sID As IHTMLElementCollection` and   `For Each TDelement In sID  
                    If InStr(1, rngURL.Value, "ups") Then sID = "tt_spStatus"` but it still seems that I'm getting a type mismatch error.  Sorry to bring this up again, but this is one of the bigger projects I'm working on, and I don't put this in focus since a lot of smaller projects are easier to complete.

Comment: @Tak - please post a new question with your issue and SO can assist you better in that way.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I've posted a new question. The code has been updated to reflect my tweaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK Ill start with the proper syntax for you to get your code going and I will edit this answer for further code

```
Sub Sample()


Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = True

Dim wsSheet As Worksheet, Rows As Long, links As Variant, IE As Object, link As Variant
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wsSheet = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

Set IE = New InternetExplorer

Rows = wsSheet.Cells(wsSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
links = wsSheet.Range("A1:A" & Rows)

With IE
    .Visible = True
    For Each link In links
        .navigate (link)
        While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
        MsgBox .Document.body.innerText
    Next link
End With

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

This will get you looping I think you had some general syntax issues which you can see the difference in my code in order to loop through in the for each the link has to be of type object or variant and links I set to variant assuming it will default to a string

Comment: Thanks for helping out with getting the loop to start up. All I have to configure now are the If statements in order to pull the right information to go into column D. The looping is working out great - it just gets slightly annoying when you're trying to break out of the macro since there's so much information flying through the message boxes haha

Comment: No Problem! try adding an iterable integer such as i outside the loop set to zero and go i = i + 1 and then set wsSheet.Range("B" & i).Value = .Document.body.innerText instead of msgbox and you can just look at it in an excel column or just press ESC

Comment: I did and tweaked it so that it will display the information I need from each order number. It works like a charm. 
@Scott Holtzman Thank you for the tip on the loops! I only had the basic `For Each TDelement In elems
                If TDelement.className = "s-result-item celwidget" And InStr(TDelement.innerHTML, AAws.Range("B" & x).Value) Then
                    AAws.Range("J" & x).Value = TDelement.ID
                    i = i + 1
                End If
            Next`
in my code, but I didn't realise I had to specify it to that degree haha.